# Accounting system, bank emulator

Tags: java, emulation, finance, accounting, financial

Do you know any accounting system emulator, that could be used free? The following requirements should be met:

- defining accounts and currencies for them
- handling balances
- provide simple transfer functionality
- keeping payment history and let you search
- user-account relation handling
- persistent storage of information
- connectivity with Java

Can you suggest any open-source or free emulator, that can provide such functionality? This is so common need in a lot of projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no standard API's as all accounting systems are different and provide different feature sets.

You're probably better off with the actual package you want to develop against with some dummy data loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I know. On the other hand sometimes to change an open source thing is faster than to write a new one